# Match elements with a given attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css, .net, telerik

I have the following HTML and I wish to add the class `HideEdit` to hide the column using CSS.

```
<th class="rgHeader" style="text-align: left;" scope="col" _events="[object Object]" control="[object Object]" UniqueName="Edit">
```

The above HTML is generated using radGrid. I am trying to hide all of the Edit columns on the page during print. I have my css configured for `@mediaPrint`. I can't use the `rgHeader` as this class is used by all of the columns in the radGrid.

In order to achieve the desired result, I have to add the `HideEdit` class to all `<th>` tags  where `UniqueName="Edit"`.

I tried something like the following:

```
$("th.rgHeader:contains('UniqueName=\"Edit\"')").addClass('HideEdit');
```

Here is the complete HTML:

```
<TR>
<TD>
<DIV id="ctl00_ctl22_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248_ctl00_ctl22_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248_ctl42Panel">
<DIV id="ctl00_ctl22_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248_ctl42">
<DIV style="WIDTH: 100%" id="ctl00_ctl22_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248Grid" class="RadGrid RadGrid_Default">
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 100%; EMPTY-CELLS: show; TABLE-LAYOUT: auto" id="ctl00_ctl22_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248Grid_ctl00" class="rgMasterTable" border="0">
<COLGROUP><COL style="WIDTH: 3%" /><COL style="WIDTH: 15%" /><COL style="WIDTH: 15%" /><COL style="WIDTH: 10%" /><COL style="WIDTH: 10%" /><COL style="WIDTH: 15%" /><COL style="WIDTH: 10%" /><COL style="WIDTH: 22%" /></COLGROUP>
<THEAD>
<TR>
<TH style="DISPLAY: none" class="rgHeader" scope="col" UniqueName="Edit">
<A title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl22$g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248$g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248Grid$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl00','')">Edit</A>
</TH>
<TH style="TEXT-ALIGN: center" class="rgHeader" scope="col" UniqueName="Parent_x0020_Program">
<A title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl22$g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248$g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248Grid$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl01','')">Parent Program</A>
</TH>
<TH style="TEXT-ALIGN: center" class="rgHeader" scope="col" UniqueName="Program">
<A title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl22$g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248$g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248Grid$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl02','')">Program</A>
</TH>
<TH style="TEXT-ALIGN: center" class="rgHeader" scope="col" UniqueName="Program_x0020_ID">
<A title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl22$g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248$g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248Grid$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl03','')">Program ID</A>
</TH>
<TH style="TEXT-ALIGN: center" class="rgHeader" scope="col" UniqueName="Group">
<A title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl22$g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248$g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248Grid$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl04','')">Group</A>
</TH>
<TH style="TEXT-ALIGN: center" class="rgHeader" scope="col" UniqueName="Investment_x0020_Envelope">
<A title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl22$g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248$g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248Grid$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl05','')">Investment Envelope</A>
</TH>
<TH style="TEXT-ALIGN: center" class="rgHeader" scope="col" UniqueName="Function">
<A title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl22$g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248$g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248Grid$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl06','')">Function</A>
</TH>
<TH style="TEXT-ALIGN: center" class="rgHeader" scope="col" UniqueName="AKA">
<A title="Click here to sort" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl22$g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248$g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248Grid$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl07','')">AKA</A>
</TH>
</TR>
</THEAD>
<TBODY>
<TR id="ctl00_ctl22_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248Grid_ctl00__0" class="rgRow" vAlign="top">
<TD vAlign="top" align="center">
<A onclick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/ProjectProfileForm.aspx?LID=228" target="_self"><IMG border="0" alt="Edit" src="/images/edititem.gif" /></A>
</TD>
<TD vAlign="top" align="center">
</TD>
<TD vAlign="top" align="center">
The Big one
</TD>
<TD vAlign="top" align="center">
PRG0001
</TD>
<TD vAlign="top" align="center">
PDN
</TD>
<TD vAlign="top" align="center">
Revenue Growth
</TD>
<TD vAlign="top" align="center">
Engineering
</TD>
<TD vAlign="top" align="center">
the dummy project for testing
</TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
<INPUT id="ctl00_ctl22_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248Grid_ClientState" type="hidden" name="ctl00_ctl22_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248Grid_ClientState" autocomplete="off" value="" /> 
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id="ctl00_ctl22_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248_AjaxLoadingPanel">
<IMG style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" src="/Images/loading6.gif" />test
</DIV>
</TD>
</TR>
```

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please rephrase your question and better include a demo to show what's the problem and your expected result based on your demo.

Comment: Maybe you should try to make some valid HTML first ;) or provide a better code sample so we can fix it for you.

Comment: If I'm not mistake, the edit th receives another class besides the rgHeader.

Answer (score 0):

```
.HideEdit{display:none;}

$('th.rgHeader').addClass('HideEdit');
```

you can use an equivalent selector to find the element numerically within the dom or element.

```
$('th:eq(0)').addClass();//this would be the first within the DOM
$('th:eq(1)','table#element').addClass();//this would be the second table header within the table with an id of element.
```

To hide an entire column, you'd either have to have a class for each column or use `eq()`

```
$('td:eq(5),td:eq(5)','table#element>tr').hide();//this will hide the 6th column within the table with the id element
```

jQuery selectors can also be given attributes

```
$('element[attribute="value"]')
```

I think this is what you mean?

```
$('th[UniqueName="Edit"]')
```

don't forget they probably not all table headers.

```
$('td[UniqueName="Edit"]')
```

I like to use this method in forms for it handyness.

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup();
```

opposed to

```
$('#username,#password,#other').keyup();
```

Try this

```
$('td:eq(0),th:eq(0)','#ctl00_ctl22_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248Grid_ctl00>tr').hide();
```

but could be styled differently. Try this also because I'm a bit confused :p

```
$('tr:eq(0)','#ctl00_ctl22_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248_g_6f2f4cde_9491_4d9a_b866_c338a5db0248Grid_ctl00').hide();
```

The second selector will make the first row disappear where all 'UniqueName' attributes seem to be. The first wil make the first 'column' disappear.

Comment: Thank you Beneto. I just added more details to the question. Please review it once again, as the above code will not work for my requirements.

Comment: @user19731 where you say 'UniqueName="Edit"' what do you mean? Is that an attribute? Or is it content?

Comment: It is the unique attribute, and it is the only identifier that we can use to distinguish columns. Here 'Edit' is the column name and 'UniqueName' is the variable used by radGrid.

Comment: Hi Beneto, thanks for your suggestion. I tried to use the provided function but an unable to hide the entire column. I just posted the completed HTML generated by radGrid for this table. See if you can have a look at it and suggest a way to find if Edit column exists and hide it during printing. Thanks

Comment: @MSingh When you say 'printing process' do you mean when the page is printed? Also do you require just the column with the <TH> with the attribute UniqueName ="edit" to be hidden?

Comment: Exactly as you described. If possible I wish to hide the column that has edit buttons.

Comment: @MSingh give that a shot :)